# Open touch keyboard windows 10 on focus event TextBox | Universal App

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, keyboard, win-universal-app

i've a problem.
I wanted a method to open touch keyboard on windows when the user click on TextBox on the wpf client.

So i've found this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("TabTip.exe");
```

But I don't have a Process library on Windows universal app.
My target is open automatically the keyboard when the textbox or text input is focused.

There is a solution for do this ? From C# code or WPF? exist a solution ?

My question it's not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886654/how-to-open-tabtip-keyboard-in-a-uwp-app-in-desktop-mode-on-button-click), because i wanted to open/close automatically a touch keyboard every time a text input has focused.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open TabTip keyboard in a UWP app in desktop mode on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886654/how-to-open-tabtip-keyboard-in-a-uwp-app-in-desktop-mode-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question makes it unclear, if your are asking about WPF or UWP.
It works by default in UWP when your app is launched on touch device. On `WPF` its a little bit different. Lately, MS changes this behavior very often. Currently, this works in WPF by default on touch device, but only if your Window does not have `WindowsStyle` property set to `None`.

Edit:
In UWP it works by default, but you have to bo on touch device. If you run your app in simulator, make sure you use touch mode.[image]

Comment: I think that the question it's clear, I need a solution to open a keyboard on windows 10. Now i use a simulator tablet, but the default doesn't open the keyboard.

Comment: But what kind of app are you writing? UWP or WPF?

Comment: I'm building an Universal Windows App using WPF for the UI and C# with MVVM pattern on the backend

Comment: I think your are messing WPF with XAML.

Comment: Are you running your app on a touch device?

Comment: I do not have a physical device, now I running on simulator

Comment: Make sure you selected touch mode on simulator (interpret mouse as touch events).

Comment: I've set the touch settings but nothing...no open keyobaord automatically